# PHP Permissions (chmod vs. suEXEC)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, security, suexec

I have an application that claims to require chmod 777 permissions for two of its directories (and their subdirectories). Instead of doing that, would suEXEC be a more secure alternative?

Comment: I highly doubt that any application should ever have 777 without posing a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would.  suPHP and/or using FastCGI would also work.

On a more general note, I'd be very wary about the coding practices (especially around security) of anyone who thought that `chmod 0777` was the solution to a permissions problem.  You might be installing an invitation to a giant pwn party on your server.

Comment: So /var/www is set to root:web where "web" is developers only (not www-data). In this case, Apache will access files under the permissions of everyone else. Will suEXEC still work given this case or should I add www-data to my "web" group?

Comment: Yes, suExec would work, although I'd still recommend using FastCGI as it doesn't have the per-request overheads of suExec.